# detect the changes between two different git users (from their last commit)?

Tags: git

How can I detect the changes (say line by line if different at all) between two different git users (and their last commit)?

```
mona@DESKTOP-0JQ770H:/mnt/c/june1st_branch$ git log --pretty=format:"%H"  --after "2017-03-30 00:00"
17e24f8f66eda0b831ed2296482c7a4d42a8a0ba
6af4704ae5e2aacbdc52b4ad3057458158656c11
c6d33cc7fe7d4a86540589efdaa42b56ccd73a73
mona@DESKTOP-0JQ770H:/mnt/c/june1st_branch$ git log --pretty=format:"%H"  --after "2017-03-29 00:00"
17e24f8f66eda0b831ed2296482c7a4d42a8a0ba
6af4704ae5e2aacbdc52b4ad3057458158656c11
c6d33cc7fe7d4a86540589efdaa42b56ccd73a73
7b86066431bc4139ef2bcbcc9ee31e248108592a
05d321cae73f46499e656f84b644dd2c9c244a5e
mona@DESKTOP-0JQ770H:/mnt/c/june1st_branch$ git log --pretty=format:"%H"  --after "2017-05-01 00:00"
17e24f8f66eda0b831ed2296482c7a4d42a8a0ba
6af4704ae5e2aacbdc52b4ad3057458158656c11
c6d33cc7fe7d4a86540589efdaa42b56ccd73a73
```

For example, March 29th was the last day user A committed to the repo (admin) and June 8th, is the last day, user B had a commit locally (not admin so can't push to master). I would like to know what are all the lines added by user B to the repo (or modified).
Here's the last git status of user B:

```
mona@DESKTOP-0JQ770H:/mnt/c/june1st_branch$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score 1):

## Finding the last commits of different autors

Given that your local `master` branch is ahead of `origin/master` and thus contains all relevant commits you can use `git log` to search the last commit of earch user:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H" -1 --author=EMAIL
```

and then compare these to commits with

```
git diff COMMIT1 COMMIT2
```

however, it may contain other changes as well, if there are commits inbetween.

to view the changes of the found commits as diffs:

```
git show COMMIT1
git show COMMIT2
```

### Explanation

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log
- `git log` shows newest first
- search of the author: `--author=` (you can also search for committer, if that differs)
- limit to 1 commit (i.e. the last one): `-1`

### Pitfalls

If the commits are on different branches, `git log` can be used

- with branch names
- with `--branches=` and a search pattern for branch names
- with `--all`, for all branches

Comment: In the second snippet, is it supposed to be `COMMIT1 COMMIT2`? :P

Comment: @ethanwu10: indeed, thanks for catching the typo! Fixed it.